# Detecting multiple values in a list

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am having trouble with this problem: I am to write a method contains3 that accepts a List of strings as a parameter and returns true if any single string occurs at least 3 times in the list, and false otherwise. I need to use a map.

When there are three instances of a word, it still does not return true; I am having trouble locating where things went wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
private static boolean contains3(List<String> thing) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String s: thing) {
        String word = s;

        if (wordCount.containsKey(word)) { // seen before.
            int count = wordCount.get(word);
            wordCount.put(word, count + 1);
        } else {
            wordCount.put(word, 1); // never seen before.
        }

        if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: When there are three instances of a word, it still does not return true; I am having trouble locating where things went wrong.

Comment: @JackL. Can't you use native method's from collections ?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I am supposed to use a map to sort things out however.

Comment: debugging would have helped

Comment: Yeah... but for some reason, my Eclipse doesn't show the variables when debugging after I downloaded my dark UI. Probably a bug; I definitely need to fix my Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
    //...
```

You should get the value using the key, in other words, the `word` you're counting.

```
if (wordCount.get(word) >= 3) {
    return true;
}
```

Note that I removed the `return false;` from this `if` statement since it will break the method in the first iteration.

---

As a suggestion, you may use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `TreeMap` to *enhance* the performance of your method since the `put` and `get` time in `HashMap` are O(1) (constant time) while [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)'s are O(log n).

Comment: Also, a `HashMap` is the right choice here rather than `TreeMap` (more efficient since there's no need for sorting).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code.

```
private static boolean contains3(List<String> thing) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        thing.add("hi");
        thing.add("hi");
        thing.add("hi");
        thing.add("hia");
        thing.add("hi3");
        for (String s: thing) {
            String word = s;

            if (wordCount.containsKey(word)) { // seen before.
                int count = wordCount.get(word);
                wordCount.put(word, count + 1);
            } else {
                wordCount.put(word, 1); // never seen before.
            }
        }
            if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running this code as you add each word:

```
        if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
```

The test will fail when the first word is added, and you'll immediately return `false`. Move that block to the end of the method, in the final line where you currently have `return false` to only make the check when you've counted all the words.

Answer (score 1):

put

```
if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

It is much more efficient to check if count is >= 3 in the initial if block

```
   if (wordCount.containsKey(word)) { // seen before.
        int count = wordCount.get(word) + 1;
        if(count >= 3) {
              return true;
        }
        wordCount.put(word, count);
    }
```

and remove the following if else block

```
    if (wordCount.containsValue(3)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```